# Make Keyboard Disappear when UITableView Scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextField at the top of my Table View, after the text field is selected I want the keyboard to disappear. I know to call `[[self view] endEditing:YES];` but I don't know how to check for the scroll. A good example of this is IMessage, when the keyboard is in view you can scroll up to collapse it, I want my table view to work inversely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. By being the table delegate (implementing `<UITableViewDelegate>`) you are also the scroll view delegate (`<UIScrollViewDelegate>`) and as such you can implement:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Then you will receive a notification whenever the table view is scrolled. You can then also use `scrollView.contentOffset` to check where the table has scrolled to (which direction it's scrolling in).

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Try other method in `UIScrollViewDelegate` if you need other behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Call `resignFirstResponder` where appropriate.

It seems you use UITextField in your cells. Use `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol to know when `UITextField` ends being edited:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```